# Why does the order matter for this recursion method?

Tags: java, if-statement, recursion

The following code is in response to a question on coding bat : http://codingbat.com/prob/p101372

This solution works...

```
public String changeXY(String str) {

if (str=="") {return "";}
else if (str.substring(0,1).equals("x") && str.length()<2) { return "y";}
else if (str.substring(0,1)!="x" && str.length()<2) {return str;}
else if (str.substring(0,1).equals("x") && str.length()>1) {return "y" +    changeXY(str.substring(1));}
else if (str.substring(0,1)!=("x")) { return str.substring(0,1) + changeXY(str.substring(1));}


return changeXY(str);

}
```

However, why does the solution not work if I simply rearrange the if-statements?
Surely the order doesn't matter. Could someone explain why the order matters in this instance/ in any instance.

Comment: Because your conditions are not mutually exclusive.  Consider `if (x == 1 && y == 2) { print("Foo"); } else if (x == 1) { print("Bar"); }`.

Comment: Most probably because you are comparing strings with `!=`. Plus, your tests are redundant

Comment: If it weren't for the `!=` I'd sketch a [Karnaugh map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably because you are comparing strings with `!=` and `==` (for the first case). This should do the trick in any order.

```
public String changeXY(String str) {
    if (str.isEmpty()) return "";
    else if (str.substring(0,1).equals("x") && str.length()<2) return "y";
    else if (!str.substring(0,1).equals("x") && str.length()<2) return str;
    else if (str.substring(0,1).equals("x") && str.length()>1) return "y" + changeXY(str.substring(1));
    else if (!str.substring(0,1).equals("x")) return str.substring(0,1) + changeXY(str.substring(1));

    return changeXY(str);
}
```

However, a "smarter" code would be :

```
public String changeXY(String str) {
    if (str.isEmpty() || (str.charAt(0) != 'x' && str.length() < 2)) return str;
    else if (str.charAt(0) == 'x') return "y" +    changeXY(str.substring(1));
    return str.charAt(0) + changeXY(str.substring(1));
}
```

In that last case, the order also matters because the tests following other tests take into account that they failed if we arrived here.